# How to exclude some text and retain others in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to create a new column that will keep some texts from column A. The new column will not contain "AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS" from the left hand side and ", (CIF) CURN" from the right hand side.

```
Name                                                    2010      2011      2012
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM ARGENTINA, (CIF) CURN       291.173   623.541   689.983
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM ARMENIA, (CIF) CURN         0.608     1.279     0.222
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM ASIA DEVELOPING, (CIF) CURN 77667.5   89057.1   96360.6
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM AUSTRIA, (CIF) CURN         925.304   911.944   982.744
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM AZERBAIJAN, (CIF) CURN      148.761   95.751    94.929
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM BAHAMAS, (CIF) CURN         2.075     2.707     3.674
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM BAHRAIN, (CIF) CURN         47.079    122.974   76.903
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM BANGLADESH, (CIF) CURN      145.684   277.727   427.356
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM BARBADOS, (CIF) CURN        1.741     2.255     2.021
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM BELARUS, (CIF) CURN         4.331     4.097     6.514
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM BELGIUM, (CIF) CURN         1567.02   1874.72   1879.72
AU AUSTRALIA - IMPORTS FROM BELIZE, (CIF) CURN          1.421     3.485     1.606
```

Comment: You can use `SUBSTITUTE()` twice to replace those parts of the text with an empty string.

Comment: If the format is the same, you can use `MID` plus `SEARCH` as well.

Comment: The MID function is not suitable here as the mid string is changing in each row, and I want those mid texts in my new column. For the moment I am first creating an extra column by extracting right hand portion of my texts, using =RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-28), and then extracting the left hand portion by =LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-6). This is working as the same number of texts is excluded in each row. Is there a way to write the two functions in one cell to avoid creating an extra column?

Answer (score 0):

Using cells to contain the two strings to be removed (for flexibility) say in Z1 and Z2 and assuming `Name` is in A1, as suggested by @Tim Williams:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,Z$1,""),Z$2,"")
```

in row2 and copied down to suit.

Alternatively, using MID and LEN:

```
=MID(A2,29,LEN(A2)-40)
```

in row2 copied down to suit.